# Embed webkit or ie8 in vb6

Tags: vb6, internet-explorer-8, webkit, embed

I was wondering if there is a way that I can embed webkit or ie8 in control in vb6. Vb6 because I want the application to run independent of any framework. And the app has to be standalone.

1. The application should work even if
   the client don't have ie8
   installed(I i should use some dll or
   something i guess)
2. The application
           should be standalone.

Any suggestions would be really helpful... All I want to make is a chromeless full screen browser with good javascript and css support, so that I can warp my html and run in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Embedding Webkit in a Visual Basic Application** 
http://vb.wikia.com/wiki/Embedding_WebKit